# Discord Bot to trigger other bots actions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make use of other bots by triggering their actions via my own bot.

Basicly somthing like :
 !dothis   .. which triggers my own bot command , 
then my bot outputs a message like !dothat  .. which is command for another bot.

Now I realized most bots dont react on bot messages for this. Is there a way to achive this?

The Idea is behind this is, that there are a lot of bots with cool functions ... So I dont have to neccecarly code up everything & instead make use of them by have another bot trigger their actions automatically .. instead of having to type ...

Comment: If the bots ignore messages from other bots (which is general practice), then there's no way to get around that on your end.

Comment: i read something about emit events , wouldnt it be possible to emit event as a user ?

Comment: When an instantiated client sees a message, its [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event is emitted. Most of the time, they check if the author is a bot (see [`User.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot)), and if so, return. This results in messages from all other bots, and from itself, being ignored. Technically speaking, you could bypass this if you use a "selfbot" which is run through a user account, but this is against the Discord Terms of Service.

Comment: alright .. guess it is not wanted .. gotta suck it up & write a few more lines myself . This would have been heaven

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible with most bots. It is very common practice to have your bot ignore other bots' messages. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Carl-bot allows me to auto feed messages. I run a scheduled poll with that from simple poll, which allows me to set everything in a text format.